# Inserting special symbol in section numbering

Tags: numbering, counters

I'm writing my thesis and I'm trying to insert a special symbol in section numbers. I have the following code in my `.sty` file:

```
\renewcommand*\thesection{\S \arabic{section}}
```

This correctly inserts the character `\S` before section numbers. However I don't want the symbol to show up in other counters related to the section counter. For example, I have the following line to number theorems:

```
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
```

For theorem 5 of section 4, this outputs[image]
I would like to remove the special symbol. How do I do that ? Do I have to redefine all of the counters I want to modify? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a known trick for this kind of things, which involves the internal command `\@seccntformat`

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname format#1\endcsname
    \csname format#1\endcsname
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname
  \fi
  \quad
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\formatsection}{\S\ \thesection}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{Title}

\begin{theorem}
This is theorem 1.1, isn't it?
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

The idea is that defining a command `\formatsection` will override the standard output in sectional titles of the `\section` level. You can define additional commands for other levels, if so wished. If you don't define, say, `\formatsubsection`, just the number will be printed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works great! I would also like to remove the chapter number and keep all other counters, that is I would like my counters to be of the form section.theorem, not chapter.section.theorem. How do I do that?

Comment: @fresh `\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}` should do. Or just `\renewcommand{\thesection}{arabic{section}}`, if you only want § 1 for the section number next to the title.

Comment: ```\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}``` worked for me. Thank you very much!