# Multi-layered numbered list with custom symbol

Tags: lists

For a small organization (club) I want to write a "constitution" in a certain format. I tried using just custom sections and subsections, which looks how I want it:

```
\titleformat{\section}{\centering\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\S\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\normalsize}{\S\thesubsection}{1em}{}    

\section{A topic}
  \subsection{This is a rule}
  \subsection{Another rule}
\section{A different topic}
  \subsection{Yet another rule}
```

[image: A statisfactory result]

But I think this might be the wrong way to do it, and I've already encountered some formatting problems. Latex doesn't know how to divide the text properly, and when I reach the end of the page, the text just sort of continues out of the bottom of the page. I first tried to fix this, but reasoned that there must exist a better way of doing this.

So does anyone know how I can replicate this format but in a better and more proper LaTeX way?

Comment: Perhaps this question and answer could be of help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/582666/inserting-special-symbol-in-section-numbering

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I don't see how that is applicable though, I've already customized the section titles as they have done in that answer. What I need is a better way to make the list in each section. Do you mean that I should use a theorem for each list item?

Comment: Then perhaps I just don't understand exactly what the issue is.  I had thought the issue was with the use of `\S` in sectioning titles and, as the referenced questions shows, how that can otherwise introduce problems with `\ref`.  If I am misunderstanding, I could delete my comment and perhaps you could edit your question to clarify more specifically what the problem is.

Comment: Okay, I tried to make the problem more clear. But I think Wilson's answer is really what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a (modified) `enumerate` list environment?

```
% itemizeprob.tex  SE 583180
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\centering\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\S\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\normalsize}{\S\thesubsection}{1em}{}    

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\S\thesection.\theenumi}

\begin{document}

\section{A topic}
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is an enumerated rule.
\item Another rule.
\end{enumerate}

  \subsection{This is a subsection rule}
  \subsection{Another rule}

\section{A different topic}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Yet another enumerated rule.
\end{enumerate}

  \subsection{Yet another subsection rule}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work well, and also looks more proper code-wise.